# How to deserialize the GraphQL server response to object?

Tags: asp.net-core, graphql

How to convert the GraphQL response to object on the client?
I do this way:

```
        var request = new GraphQLRequest
        {
            Query = @"{customer(id:4){id,firstName,lastName,contact,email}}"
        };
        var jsonSerializer = new njs.NewtonsoftJsonSerializer();
        using var graphQLClient = new GraphQLHttpClient("https://localhost:5011/graphql/", jsonSerializer);
        //var response = await graphQLClient.SendQueryAsync<Customer>(request);
        var response = await graphQLClient.SendQueryAsync<dynamic>(request);
        var graphQLQueryType = @"customer";
        var cust = response;//.Data..customer;

        var stringResult = response.Data.ToString();
        var resultzzz = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Customer>>(stringResult);
```

and the result as a string is:
stringResult = "{\r\n "customer": {\r\n "id": "4",\r\n "firstName": "Name#4",\r\n "lastName": "LastName#4",\r\n "contact": "Contact#4",\r\n "email": "you#4@mai.com"\r\n }\r\n}"

It is ok.
But I need to deserialize this response to object class Customer.

and this
var resultzzz = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(stringResult);
gives me:
ex = {"Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[GraphQL.Client.Example.Customer]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.\r\nTo fix this error eith...
`

What I do wrong? How to fix it?